# Multiple remote desktop connections to same session

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc

I need to connect to the remote desktop twice - because of pair programming on the remote machine - now, when one coder connects, other is disconnected.

My idea is to install tightvnc or some other vnc to the remote machine, and let one coder use remote desktop and other log in via vnc.  Any better/easier solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use Windows Server, once connected through RDP, you can right click a console session in Task Manager and select Remote Control, to share the same session.  You can also do the same with the [termsrv.dll patch](http://deepxw.blogspot.com/search/label/Universal%20Termsrv.dll%20Patch) on desktop Windows.

Another option is [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx), and IIRC, you can do the same with [CrossLoop](http://www.crossloop.com/), both of which are easier to setup than VNC (no port forwarding needed if connecting through the internet).

Comment: On 2014 Jan 31, after a corporate takeover, Crossloop's products and services became unavailable.  TeamViewer works fine, and installation on Linux and Win7 was dead easy.  Nice multimonitor support, too.