# Allow to users to RDP into same Session on Same User

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, session, multiple-users

So im running a console application that logs a lot of information and also contains a user interface that 2 people will have to access, so hear me out - The 2 people the developers me and a friend, we always are talking when we are on the server, so we wanted a solution to allow both of us into the same user and session and we devised to install TeamViewer but we soon found out when we closed the RDP the session got frozen but the applications still was being executed in the background but TeamViewer could not get the screen.

The main question being asked is there a way possible for both of us to connect into RDP on the same session at the same time using Windows Remote Desktop.

The operating system is Windows Server 2012 RC hosted on OVH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple remote desktop connections to same session](http://superuser.com/questions/206658/multiple-remote-desktop-connections-to-same-session)

Comment: I believe I did this once on Windows with an old version of VNC, but I'm not sure...